# Why didn't the Death Eaters swear an Unbreakable Vow to obey Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, unbreakable-vow

Someone on Quora asked why Voldemort didn't make his followers swear an Unbreakable Vow to follow/obey him, thus insuring any who betrayed or defied the Dark Lord would die doing so- is there an in-universe reason Voldemort couldn't or didn't do this? Or is it really not so simple?